# Learn Cognitive Empathy

Tags: cognitive-psychology, social-psychology, empathy, cognitive-development, cognitive-enhancement

I recently stumbled upon some psychology sites and learned more about the 3 types of empathy. Since I want to understand everyone better, I want to improve my skills at empathy. I found a lot of tutorials for the first 2 empathy types but nothing really about the last: Cognitive Empathy. The only [article](https://www.inc.com/justin-bariso/there-are-actually-3-types-of-empathy-heres-how-they-differ-and-how-you-can-develop-them-all.html) I found that was related to it wasn't much helpful. Since I don't want to give up that easily, I'm now asking you for help: How to learn and use cognitive empathy?

Thank You

Edit: I've found an related [question](https://www.quora.com/How-can-you-improve-your-cognitive-empathy) on another Forum site. This answers the first part of my question: How to learn it? But now the second part: how to use it?

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. *"We often hear about the need for more empathy in the world"*, yet we need to be mindful that you don't empathise too much. There is a balance which is needed. (See related question at [Can you really have "excessive empathy"?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/21258/7604).)